# When does the WPF SplashScreen close?

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I'm working on a custom splash-screen (since the [standard one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't fit my needs). But there is one option I'd like to have from it - auto-close. But to implement it, I need to understand how the common `SplashScreen` selects the moment to close.

So, is there any sort of event to message the splash screen, to tell it that it should be closed? What event does the common splash-screen use, at least?

Comment: Close it explicitly. Usually there is a main window, close splash screen when it's rendered (in wpf its [`ContentRendered`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered.aspx) event). [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/SplashScreen.cs,9c43c23f03d92271) is `SplashScreen` sources if you are willing to dig into them.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you refer to visual studio?

Comment: Usually its as simple as whatever app type thing you run to launch the splash as early as possible, close it once all the loading, setting up, whatever has taken place. this maybe done through threading whatever..

Comment: @Sinatr: Noticed. Never had such a circumstance. Deleted.

Comment: @derape, because in question, I'm refering to standart SplashScreen, which is actually feature of Visual Studio (or at least C# part of it)

Comment: @lentinant well I don't think there is something like a "standard" splashscreen and that is also not part of C#, in fact, I don't think that there is a default control within the .net framework for a splashscreen. It really depends on your requirements for your splashscreen and how you want it to behave

Comment: @derape I think it's a case of assuming that because WPF apps are built in Visual Studio, WPF things are "features of Visual Studio". Also, the question does link to a [`SplashScreen` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that exists in WPF (which I'll admit I hadn't heard of either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having an image file with Build Action set to Splash Screen, you can have more control over the splash screen by creating and showing it yourself in the Application's OnStartup event handler. The show method of SplashScreen has a parameter to stop it closing automatically and then you can tell it when to close using the Close method:

Firstly remove the StartupUri tag from App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Splash_Screen.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
    <Application.Resources> 

    </Application.Resources> 
</Application>
```

Change the `Build Action` of your image file to `Resource`

Then create and show the splash screen in the OnStartup event handler:

```
public partial class App : Application 
    { 
        private const int MINIMUM_SPLASH_TIME = 1500; // Miliseconds 
        private const int SPLASH_FADE_TIME = 500;     // Miliseconds 

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) 
        { 
            // Step 1 - Load the splash screen 
            SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splash.png"); 
            splash.Show(false, true); 

            // Step 2 - Start a stop watch 
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch(); 
            timer.Start(); 

            // Step 3 - Load your windows but don't show it yet 
            base.OnStartup(e); 
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow(); 

            // Step 4 - Make sure that the splash screen lasts at least two seconds 
            timer.Stop(); 
            int remainingTimeToShowSplash = MINIMUM_SPLASH_TIME - (int)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds; 
            if (remainingTimeToShowSplash > 0) 
                Thread.Sleep(remainingTimeToShowSplash); 

            // Step 5 - show the page 
            splash.Close(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SPLASH_FADE_TIME)); 
            main.Show(); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thx for answer, but, actually, I have intention to build my own SplashScreen (which can be shown or hidden any time). Default SplashScreen fades right when application window loads (no later or earlier). So, question was - how he knows when to fade.

Comment: You must control that yourself. I would show the splash screen for a set time (e.g. 3 seconds) and then show MainWindow. I'm guessing you want to show MainWindow and close splash as soon as MainWindow is ready to show. This would probably be immediately, but depends entirely on what you are doing before showing MainWindow. Do your loading of data, etc, and when that is finished, call SplashScreen.Close and MainWindow.Show.

Comment: Well, after few experiments, your solution gave me way to go. For now, i'm creating splash screen in App constructor, and closing it in OnStartup. It actually raised very weird bug, but it is another question.

Answer (score 4):

The WPF SplashScreen class uses a very simple trick, it calls [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/SplashScreen.cs,c0dbd82be0752bf6).

The expectation is that the UI thread is grinding away getting the program initialized and is therefore not dispatching anything.  It is "hung".  Not forever of course, as soon as it is done, it re-enters the dispatcher loop and now the BeginInvoked method gets a chance, the [ShowCallback()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/SplashScreen.cs,b644838e80f0ca70) method runs.  Poorly named, should be "CloseCallback" :)  A 0.3 second fade covers up any additional delay in getting the main window to render.

In general, calling Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() on the UI thread looks like a weird hack but is very useful.  An excellent way to solve gritty re-entrancy problems.

Very simple, not the only way to do it.  The main window's Load event could be a useful trigger.